# How to handle Proxy with Sudo on VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, proxy, wget

I have Ubuntu installed on a VirtualBox VM and I am using NAT. The host network requires NTLM proxy authentication to work. I tried `export HTTP_PROXY=proxy.mycomp.com:80` & `HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY` but they do not seem to help with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_PROXY` wouldn't work so I went ahead and edited `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` adding...

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "proxy.my.com:80";
```

This file did not exist and I had to create it.